# Is it possible to change gmail sync interval in Android or ios?

Tags: android, gmail

Is it possible to change gmail syn interval in Android or ios? Can I change it through OS or through any filesystem provided by the gmail application?

I can do that in ios in the system settings. But is there a programming way? Any API?

I have found in android, there is a android.content.PeriodicSync class. Is that useful?

Thanks，

Comment: In the settings / accounts you can manage the update interval. By default it should be push-mail which means something like zero time ;)

Comment: @rekire But I want to do it in a programming way.....:>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s definitely no way to do this programmatically on iOS—third-party apps don’t even have access to the mail accounts, let alone their sync settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you root your phone, give it a custom ROM that is editable you can change every aspect of your phone.